# Notification count not updated when page loads first time angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have to add the count for notification in header(navbar) when page loads first. 
Here if page loads , the counter added in notification. But when i load at first time it does not update.

I set the navbar fixed. when i console the index controller at first time not updated. If i loads again its updated

Am getting the $scope.count from webservice stored as localstorage.

HTML

```
  <a class="notify" ng-click="headernotifi()" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="not-value1" ng-class="{'not-value': count > 0}" ng-cloak>{{count}}</span></a>

//App Config
var app = angular.module('communicator', [
                                        'ui.router',
                                        'angularMoment',
                                        'setFiters'
                                    ]
                        ); 

//Route Config
```

I used state provider to route the files. Below the code
    app.config(

```
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider)
    {
      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
      $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
      delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

      $stateProvider
      .state('dsn', 
      {
          url:"/dsn",
          templateUrl:"design_and_selection.html",
          controller:"Design_Controller"
      }
      )
         }
)
```

Here the controller to get the notification count.

```
app.controller("indexController",function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, $stateParams, GetHostUrl, $state, $timeout, $rootScope, $localStorage) {
          //$rootScope.loggedInUserName = $localStorage.userName;
          $scope.loggedInUserName=$localStorage.userName;
          $scope.getnotification=$localStorage.getnotification;


          $scope.count= "";
          if($scope.getnotification)
          {  
          for(var i=0;i<$scope.getnotification.notifications.length;i++)
          {  
          $scope.count= 1;
          if($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].status==0)
          {
            $scope.count = $scope.count + i;
            console.log($scope.count);
          }
          }
          } 
          console.log($scope.count);
          $scope.clicker=1;
          $scope.headernotifi= function()
          {
            $scope.clicker=0;
            $scope.count="";
          }
          if($scope.getnotification)
          {
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.getnotification.notifications.length;i++)
            {
            if($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].message=="Conversation Reviewing")
            {
            $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].getreviewer="review";
            }
            if($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].message=="Conversation Approved")
            {
            $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].getreviewer="approve";
            }
            }
               for(var i=0;i<$scope.getnotification.notifications.length;i++)
            {
            if($scope.getnotification.notifications[i].updateTime)
            {
            var c= $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].updateTime;

            $scope.getnotification.notifications[i].gettime="c";
            }
            }
            }
    }
```

Sorry cant able to place the code fully. Anyone please help on this.

Comment: where you want  `$scope.count` to get displayed? and you have the same if condition twice in your code.

Comment: <a class="notify" ng-click="headernotifi()" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="not-value1" ng-class="{'not-value': count > 0}" ng-cloak>{{count}}</span></a> in header

Comment: if conditon for two different things

Comment: if `if($scope.getnotification)` this condition fails, `count` never gets a value, check if it is passing

Comment: Am not getting response if condition fails also.

Comment: checked it in else part

Comment: you does not have else condition. Please add else condition.

Comment: added and checked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133958/discussion-between-idris-and-sravan).